# Centre of a quotient of Wreath Product

Tags: group-theory

I was doing some work and came across the following problem. In the following fix an integer $s\ge 2$.

Let $i\ge 0$ and $C_{i}$ be a finite cyclic $2$-group of size $2^{s-i+1}$.

Let $W_{i}=C_{i}\wr P_i$ where $P_i$ is the $i$-th fold itertaed wreath product of group generated by the permuation $(1,2)$.

Suppose $B_{i}$ is the base group of $W_i$ that is $B_i$ is the direct product of $2^i$ copies of $C_{i}$. If $Z(W_{i})) = Z_i$ then

> Is it true that $Z(W_i/B_i)=Z_{i-1}B_i/B_i$ for $i\ge 1$?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am struggling with your notation. The group $W_i$ and hence also $Z_i$ appear to depend on $|C_i|$ (I would normally expect $C_i$ to denote a cyclic group of order $i$, that is probably not the case here.) But then $Z_{i-1}$ is a subgroup of $W_{i-1}$ and not of $W_i$, so I cannot make any sense of the equation $Z(W_i/B_i) = Z_{i-1}B_i/B_i$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have edited the question, does it make more sense sow? please feel free to comment. I am happy to discuss more. Thanks.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense because $Z_{i-1}$ is not a subgroup of $W_i$. In general, $Z_i \cong C_i$. For example, let $s=3$. Then $W_2 = C_2 \wr P_2$, with $|C_2| = 4$. Then $W_2/B_2 \cong P_2$ is dihedral of order $8$ and has centre of order $2$. But $Z_1 = Z(W_1)$ is cyclic of order $8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I actually made the question more elaborate here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354200/centre-of-a-quotient-of-wreath-product  
I will be really helpful for any help there.